# How to allocate a dynamic memory zone for a character string in C

Tags: c, memory-management, malloc, command-line-arguments, c-strings

Why doesn't this code work?  What I have been trying to do is make a dynamic allocation for an unknown user input length of an array using `int main(int ac, char ** ac)` and `malloc()`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int ac, char **av)
{
    char *str;
    int i;
    str = malloc(sizeof(char) * (ac + 1));
    i = 0;
    if(str[i] != '\0')
    {
    i = i + 1;
    printf("%s\n\t", str);
    }
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: What would you like the usage of the tool to be -- how does the user specify the input length. What would you like the output to be?

Comment: What's the value of ac ? You're not filling the char array you're allocated  with any  data. Why are you incrementing i ?

Comment: it should bassically be able to take any lenghth of what as been inputed and for now to be the ouput the same as what he entered so for example if i input "moon" then the ouput should be "moon" as well

Comment: Not doing nothing is not the same as not working, `str` is empty...

Comment: You just allocate memory, what do you want to be prints?

Comment: `sizeof(char)` == 1 its useless

Comment: Can you tell us what this program is supposed to do? For example, you are not taking any input in this program, except for `ac` which is the number of command-line arguments. So this program allocates memory based on the number of command-line arguments, them maybe prints some gibberish. Is that what you wanted it to do? Do you know how this program works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ac is not the length of any argument, but rather the argument count.
When the user specifies one argument this will always be 2.

If the program should only output the first argument you can just do:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    if(argc == 2)
        printf("%s\n", argv[1]);
    return 0;
}
```

If you want to load the argument into a string you have to get it's length.
This can for example be done with the strlen() function:

```
#include <stdio.h> /* for printf */
#include <stdlib.h> /* for malloc and free */
#include <string.h> /* for strlen and strcpy */

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    if(argc == 2) {
        char *input_string;
        int input_string_length;

        input_string_length = strlen(argv[1]);
        /* strlen() does not include the '\0' in the length */
        input_string = malloc((input_string_length + 1) * sizeof(char));
        strcpy(input_string, argv[1]);

        printf("%s\n", input_string);
        free(input_string);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

- Name the parameters of main() in the standardized way: `int argc, char *argv[]`.
- (note that `argv[0]` is the name of the executable, which may or may not be of interest to you)
- First you need to allocate `argc` number of pointers to character. Optionally with a NULL sentinel value at the end if that makes sense for your program - don't confuse this with null termination though.
- So you should rather have something like `char** str_table = malloc(sizeof(*str_table) * argc);`
- For each item in `str_table`, allocate additional memory for `strlen(argv[i]) + 1` characters, the actual data. In this case the +1 is for null termination and it is mandatory.
- `strcpy` from `argv[i]` to your own array.

Comment: Parameters of main can have any names.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Yes they _can_ have any name, but there is no reason to rename them. There's nothing stopping me from naming my cat "Dog" either, just because I can.

Answer (score 0):

`ac` doesn't represent user input length (as you have been trying to allocate memory for `ac+1`) + `str` points to a raw memory location without any valid data, even then if you want to go with `ac` then:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>         //added for memset

int main(int ac, char **av)
{
    char *str;
    int i;                  //USELESS
    str = malloc(sizeof(char) * (ac + 1));  //str points to a memory (if allocated) which contains garbage
    i = 0;             //NO USE
    if(str)   //checks if memory has been allocated - NO INCREMENT NEEDED OR VALID
    {                               
        printf("Memory has been successfully allocated");
        memset(str,'\0',ac+1);  //added for NULL termination
    }

    return(0); 
}
```

In case you are trying to allocate memory on the stack, you may also look for VLA.

Answer (score 0):

There are some logic error in your code.

`int ac` is the number of arguments.
`char **av` contain the arguments.

For example : `./program arg1 arg2`
`av[0]` is gonna be "./program"
`av[1]` is gonna be "arg1"
`av[2]` is gonna be "arg2"
`av[2][0]` is gonna be "a"

Now if you just want the size of the first argument you can use strlen() :
 `int size = strlen(av[1]);`

What you need instead of your if statement is a while loop to go throught all the elements of av.
For example :

```
int i = 0;
while (i <= ac) {  
    printf("%s", av[i]);
    ...Your code...
    i++;
}
```

Comment: `av[0]: ./program`

Answer (score 0):

This statement

```
str = malloc(sizeof(char) * (ac + 1));
```

does not make sense.

Moreover the allocated array was not initialized. So this statement

```
if(str[i] != '\0')
```

results in undefined behavior.

It seems what you are trying to do is to output command line parameters by copying them in dynamically allocated arrays.

If so then the program can look the following way

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main( int argc, char * argv[] ) 
{

    if ( argc > 1 )
    {
        char **s = malloc( ( argc - 1 ) * sizeof( char *) );

        for ( int i = 0; i < argc - 1; i++ )
        {
            s[i] = malloc( strlen( argv[i+1] ) + 1 );
            strcpy( s[i], argv[i+1] );
        }

        for ( int i = 0; i < argc - 1; i++ )
        {
            puts( s[i] );
        }

        for ( int i = 0; i < argc - 1; i++ ) free( s[i] );
        free( s );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

If to run the program like for example

```
program Hello World
```

then the output will be

```
Hello
World
```

You can add yourself checks to the program that the memory allocations were successful.